# Why does my session information only work sometimes?

Tags: php

This is very annoying, I have a website up and when you login there is the following code :

```
$_SESSION['user-id']       = $row['id'];
          $_SESSION['user-first']    = $row['first'];
          $_SESSION['user-last']     = $row['last'];
          $_SESSION['user-email']    = $row['email'];
          $_SESSION['user-username'] = $row['username'];
          $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
          $_SESSION['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
```

Now the problem is that this the frontend and the backend files all work on my localhost but on the live website it doesn't work. For example in my home.php page (the first page you visit after logging in) has a session_start() at the beginning of the file and then later in the file I use the following code :

```
<?php
      foreach (getGroups($_SESSION['user-id']) as $groupVars) {
            #echo var_dump($groupVars);
            $gname  = $groupVars['group_name'];
            $gid    = $groupVars['groups_id'];
            $gowner = $groupVars['owner_id'];
```

(+ some other php stuff after)
And that code works fine, and it successfully retrieves session info. But then when home.php uses this function :

```
function ajaxLoad(page, id, id2){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('mainpage');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
      load_messages;
        }
    }
  timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    var queryString = "?id=" + id + "&id2=" + id2 + "&userTimezone=" + timezone;
    //alert(page + queryString);
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", page + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

It displays the friends.php page. In the friends.php page there is a session_start() and it tries to retrieve session info in the following code :

```
  <?php
      foreach (showFriends($_SESSION['user-id']) as $friendId) {
        $ids = $friendId['user_two'];
        foreach (transformIdToUsername($ids) as $friendUsername) {
          $usernames = $friendUsername['username'];
          foreach (findUserAvatar($ids) as $avatarr) {
            $avatar = $avatarr['avatar'];
            echo "<div style='float: left; width: 100%; margin-top: 7.5px;'><div class='userpic' style='background-image: url($avatar); float: left; margin-left: 10px;'></div><p class='numoffriends' style='line-height: 30px; float: left; margin-left: 10px;'>$usernames</p><input style='float: left; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 6.5px;' type='submit' id=\"$usernames\" name='unfriend' onclick='unfriend(\"$usernames\")' value='Unfriend'><input type='hidden' name='username' value='$usernames'></div><br>";
          }
        }
      }
       ?>
```

And the code works in the localhost version but for some reason, it can't retrieve the session info.

But then when home.php does some XMLHttpRequest magic and retrieves some info from a backend file that uses session info successfully. Why does the session info only work sometimes and why does it only not work in the live version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Session is based on cookie, so make sure the cookie contains sessionid is sent for each request.

Comment: How do you send the session id and does it appear in `$_REQUEST`? Does the session id change during your tests?

Comment: how do I make sure the cookie contains the session id? And if it works in my localhost shouldn't it work in the live version? + when I inspect my website page it says there is a cookie called PHPSESSID